# How to refer to Component from within Stylesheet? -React Native

Tags: react-native

Brand new to React Native. I was playing around with a snack I found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style). Below is what I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class LotsOfStyles extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.myColor = 'blue'
        this.state = {myColor: 'red')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.myStyle}>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    myStyle: {
        color: this.myColor,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
    },
});
```

The above code does not crash; indeed it outputs "Lorem Ipsum" as expected. However, the color of the text is not blue - it's black, indicating that the color of the style sheet is not being read correctly.

Now my knowledge of RN is very rudimentary, but if my understanding is correct, `this` in RN has a very different scope that other languages. Again, further assuming my understanding is correct, `this` in the above example refers to `styles`, and therefore does not see the `myColor` prop in the class.

So my question is: how do you reference the actual class?

Or is referring to the class from the style sheet considered bad practice and should be avoided entirely? (and if this is the case, what is the "good" practice?)

Thanks,

Comment: this.color in the constructor refers only on `LotsOfStyles` only so you need to add `color:'blue'` in your StyleSheet

Comment: Try state = {  myColor :  "blue" }  in your constructor and then in the stylesheet try to access color like this = color: this.state.myColor

Comment: @yesIamFaded I've already tried doing exactly that, but I get an error `myColor is undefined` when I try to access it via this.state.color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have predefined colors then use it in constants 
If you want to change the colors on some events then maintain it in state variable
**Sample code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
const myColor = 'blue'
export default class LotsOfStyles extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({ color: 'red' })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.myStyle}>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.myStyle, { color: this.state.color }]}>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myStyle: {
    color: myColor,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work. the key for me was to bring the declaration of myColor outside of the class. (line 3 in your example)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to update your color then set as a constant...

```
const colorBlue = 'blue'
```

If you are using this color on multiple places then create a class Color.js and write this code like this

```
export default {
    blue: 'blue',
    black: 'black'
}
```

In which class you want to use it just import Color class and set Color like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    myStyle: {
        color: Color.blue,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
    },
});
```

In case you are changing color on run time then set color on state

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({ color: 'red' })
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    myStyle: {
        color: this.state.color,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
    },
});
```